# How i can use intl-tel-input jQuery library within ionic 2

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, ionic2

How i can use this `jQuery` library https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input within `ionic 2`.

Comment: it is related to ionic2 not concern with angular2

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: // First install jQuery
`npm install --save jquery` then `import * as $ from 'jquery';` but my question how i can use the `intl-tel-input ` library within `ioni2`

Answer (score 2):

i've used third party library named [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input).

**1- First install jQuery**

```
npm install --save jquery
```

Now, within any of the app files import `jquery` like

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

and it will using like

```
$('#elemId').width();
```

**2- install intl-tel-input library**

```
npm install intl-tel-input --save
```

Now, within any of the app files import `int-tel-input` like

```
import 'intl-tel-input';
```

and using like below:

```
ngOnInit(): any {
    let telInput = $("#elemtId");
    let output = $("#output");

    telInput.intlTelInput();
    // listen to "keyup", but also "change" to update when the user selects a country
    telInput.on("keyup change", function() {
      var intlNumber = telInput.intlTelInput("getNumber");
      if (intlNumber) {
        output.text("International: " + intlNumber);
      } else {
        output.text("Please enter a number below");
      }
    });
  }
```

**home.html**

```
<p id="output">Please enter a number below</p>
<input id="elemtId" type="tel">
```

**ionic info**

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.12.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175
```

Comment: Error VM1128 vendor.js:52957 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: telInput.intlTelInput is not a function
TypeError: telInput.intlTelInput is not a function